# Connected set, intermediate value property

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Could anyone help me to solve this one?

Suppose W is a path-connected region, that is, given any two points of W there is a continuous path joining them. If f is a continuous function on W, use the intermediate-value theorem to show that there is at least one point in W at which the value of f is equal to the average of f over W, that is, the integral of fover W divided by the volume of W. (Compare this with the mean-value theorem for double integrals.) What happens if W is not connected?

Comment: For disconnected $W$: In one dimension let $W=(0,1)\cup (2,3).$ Let $f(x)=0$ for $x\in (0,1)$ and $f(x)=1$ for $x\in (2,3).$ The average of $f$ over $W$ is $1/2.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $$v = \frac{1}{\mathrm{vol}(W)}\int_W f$$
If $f$ is the constant function always equal to $v$, then we are done. Otherwise, suppose that there exists $x_0\in W$ such that $f(x_0) \neq v$. Without loss of generality, suppose that $f(x_0) < v$. Since $f$ is continuous, there must be some $x_1\in W$ such that $f(x_1)>v$ (why?). Now let $\gamma: [0,1]\to W$ be a path from $x_0$ to $x_1$, since $W$ is path connected. Then $g = f\circ \gamma$ is a continuous function from $[0,1]$ to $\Bbb{R}$, with $g(0)<v<g(1)$. Due to the IVT, there exists $y\in [0,1]$ such that $g(y) = f(\gamma(y)) = v$.

Can you think of a disconnected $W$ for which the result fails?